# Texture lookup into rendered FBO is off by half a pixel

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, shader

I have a scene that is rendered to texture via FBO and I am sampling it from a fragment shader, drawing regions of it using primitives rather than drawing a full-screen quad: I'm conserving resources by only generating the fragments I'll need.

To test this, I am issuing the exact same geometry as my texture-render, which means that the rasterization pattern produced should be exactly the same: When my fragment shader looks up its texture with the varying coordinate it was given it should match up perfectly with the other values it was given.

Here's how I'm giving my fragment shader the coordinates to auto-texture the geometry with my fullscreen texture:

```
// Vertex shader
uniform mat4 proj_modelview_mat;
out vec2 f_sceneCoord;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = proj_modelview_mat * vec4(in_pos,0.0,1.0);
    f_sceneCoord = (gl_Position.xy + vec2(1,1)) * 0.5;
}
```

I'm working in 2D so I didn't concern myself with the perspective divide here. I just set the sceneCoord value using the clip-space position scaled back from [-1,1] to [0,1].

```
uniform sampler2D scene;
in vec2 f_sceneCoord;
//in vec4 gl_FragCoord;
in float f_alpha;   
out vec4 out_fragColor;
void main (void) {
    //vec4 color = texelFetch(scene,ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy - vec2(0.5,0.5)),0);
    vec4 color = texture(scene,f_sceneCoord);
    if (color.a == f_alpha) {
        out_fragColor = vec4(color.rgb,1);
    } else
        out_fragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

Notice I spit out a red fragment if my alpha's don't match up. The texture render sets the alpha for each rendered object to a specific index so I know what matches up with what.

Sorry I don't have a picture to show but it's very clear that my pixels are off by `(0.5,0.5)`: I get a thin, one pixel red border around my objects, on their bottom and left sides, that pops in and out. It's quite "transient" looking. The giveaway is that it only shows up on the bottom and left sides of objects.

Notice I have a line commented out which uses `texelFetch`: This method works, and I no longer get my red fragments showing up. However I'd like to get this working right with `texture` and normalized texture coordinates because I think more hardware will support that. Perhaps the real question is, is it possible to get this right without sending in my viewport resolution via a uniform? There's gotta be a way to avoid that!

Update: I tried shifting the texture access by half a pixel, quarter of a pixel, one hundredth of a pixel, it all made it worse and produced a solid border of wrong values all around the edges: It seems like my `gl_Position.xy+vec2(1,1))*0.5` trick sets the right values, but sampling is just off by just a little somehow. This is quite strange... See the red fragments? When objects are in motion they shimmer in and out ever so slightly. It means the alpha values I set aren't matching up perfectly on those pixels.

[image: transient red fragments indicate a texture sampling mis-match]

It's not critical for me to get pixel perfect accuracy for that alpha-index-check for my actual application but this behavior is just not what I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first consider dropping that `f_sceneCoord` varying and just using `gl_FragCoord / screenSize` as texture coordinate (you already have this in your example, but the `-0.5` is rubbish), with `screenSize` being a uniform (maybe pre-divided). This should work almost exact, because by default `gl_FragCoord` is at the pixel center (meaning `i+0.5`) and OpenGL returns exact texel values when sampling the texture at the texel center (`(i+0.5)/textureSize`).

This may still introduce very very very slight deviations form exact texel values (if any) due to finite precision and such. But then again, you will likely want to use a filtering mode of `GL_NEAREST` for such one-to-one texture-to-screen mappings, anyway. Actually your exsiting `f_sceneCoord` approach may already work well and it's just those small rounding issues prevented by `GL_NEAREST` that create your artefacts. But then again, you still don't need that `f_sceneCoord` thing.

**EDIT:** Regarding the portability of `texelFetch`. That function was introduced with GLSL 1.30 (~SM4/GL3/DX10-hardware, ~GeForce 8), I think. But this version is already required by the new `in/out` syntax you're using (in contrast to the old `varying/attribute` syntax). So if you're not gonna change these, assuming `texelFetch` as given is absolutely no problem and might also be slightly faster than `texture` (which also requires GLSL 1.30, in contrast to the old `texture2D`), by circumventing filtering completely.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up GL_NEAREST. That is likely to resolve the issue because I can see how linear filtering with even a very slightly different precision based error can result in my check failing. I'll try that first chance I get. I do find my `f_sceneCoord` solution to be more elegant than using `FragCoord` and a screen size uniform: It works independent of me having to keep track of a screen size uniform... Less complexity is always good.

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once! Have an upvote and an accept.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to debug with glslDevil and it required me to switch back to 1.2 syntax so I changed it all back to `varying/attribute` and `texture2D`... glslDevil still doesn't show me any values though. Anyways that doesn't matter, what's good is `GL_NEAREST` produces perfect results. Turns out in my actual implementation I'll still need to use `GL_LINEAR` anyway so things look smooth, but I'm really glad to have gotten to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in perfect X,Y [0,1] with no rounding errors that's great... But sometimes - especially if working with polar coords, you might consider aligning your calculated coords to the texture 'grid'...

I use:

```
// align it to the nearest centered texel
curPt -= mod(curPt, (0.5 / vec2(imgW, imgH)));
```

works like a charm and I no longer get random rounding errors at the screen edges...